# horizontal space using subfloat

Tags: spacing, horizontal-spacing

I'm trying to place three figure side by side, the problem is that I don't know how to reduce the horizontal space between the figures that I want to put equal to zero.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=0pt,captionskip=0.5pt}
%\centering
\subfloat{
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{Analysis/Histogram/B0.pdf}}
\subfloat[][]{
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{Analysis/Histogram/B1.pdf}}
\subfloat[][]{
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{Analysis/Histogram/B2.pdf}}
\caption{Histogram of the Asymmetry for Detector B. The Asymmetries are corrected removing the data without polarization. The raw asymmetries are multiplied by $\frac{1}{P}$}
\label{fig:AsymmtriesB0B1B2}
\end{figure}
```

the output

[image]

the preamble of the file is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,notitlepage,openright]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{frontespizio}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={.}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}
%\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{comment}

\tikzfeynmanset{every blob = {minimum size = 3mm}}
\newcommand{\commento}[1]{}
\newcommand{\Lagr}{\mathcal{L}}
%{\bfseries #1 \medskip}
\newcommand{\transv}{transverse asymmetry }
\pagestyle{headings}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}
%\setlength\intextsep{2pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt}
\author{Adriano del Vincio}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show your result, we do not have your images ...

Comment: you are adding spaces use `%` at ends of lines

Comment: I have to use % where?

Comment: Use `\subfloat{%` and `subfloat[][]{%`, or remove the linebreak between `\subfloat{`/`\subfloat[][]{` and `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Ok, I did it, but nothig has changes

Comment: If there is still space, then it is part of the images that you include. Either trim the images in the pdf file using image processing software, or use the parameters of `\includegraphics` to specify a view port.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I found that I didn't use bbox_inches='tight' when I generated this particula plots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=0pt,captionskip=0.5pt}
\subfloat[][]{% <== remove extra space here
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}}
\subfloat[][]{% <== remove extra space here
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}}
\subfloat[][]{% <== remove extra space here
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{example-image-c.pdf}}
\caption{Histogram of the Asymmetry for Detector B. The Asymmetries are corrected removing the data without polarization. The raw asymmetries are multiplied by $\frac{1}{P}$}
\label{fig:AsymmtriesB0B1B2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It also works with the full preamble given in the original post:
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,notitlepage,openright]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{frontespizio}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={.}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}
%\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{comment}

\tikzfeynmanset{every blob = {minimum size = 3mm}}
\newcommand{\commento}[1]{}
\newcommand{\Lagr}{\mathcal{L}}
%{\bfseries #1 \medskip}
\newcommand{\transv}{transverse asymmetry }
\pagestyle{headings}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t}
%\setlength\intextsep{2pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 1.0pt}
\author{Adriano del Vincio}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=0pt,captionskip=0.5pt}
\subfloat[][]{% <== remove extra space here
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}}
\subfloat[][]{% <== remove extra space here
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}}
\subfloat[][]{% <== remove extra space here
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{example-image-c.pdf}}
\caption{Histogram of the Asymmetry for Detector B. The Asymmetries are corrected removing the data without polarization. The raw asymmetries are multiplied by $\frac{1}{P}$}
\label{fig:AsymmtriesB0B1B2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Really strange, for me it still not working. I'm compiling with lualatex.

Comment: @AdrianoDelVincio Wrap the command `\fbox` around `\includegraphics`, like so: `\fbox{\includegraphics{...}}`. This will draw the border of the image. Any space that you see inside is part of the image, and has to be cropped by image processing software or by the parameters of `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
%\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=0pt,captionskip=0.5pt}
%\centering
\setkeys{Gin}{width = 0.33\textwidth}
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics{Analysis/Histogram/B0.pdf}}\hfill%
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics{Analysis/Histogram/B1.pdf}}\hfill%
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics{Analysis/Histogram/B2.pdf}}
\caption{Histogram of the Asymmetry for Detector B. The Asymmetries are corrected removing the data without polarization. The raw asymmetries are multiplied by $\frac{1}{P}$}
\label{fig:AsymmtriesB0B1B2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]